# SAT historical document vocabulary list

Tags: vocabulary

I have difficulty with paired-passage because of the vocabulary range from historical documents. In The Complete guide to SAT Reading by Erica L.Meltzer, I read that it is good to go through AP US History passages.

The problem is all the APUSH wordlist provide the list of public figures, treties, etc, but not 'common words' that can be used in historical documents. Could anyone suggest where to find these "antiquated words"?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's being asked for here, but I do know that requests for recommendations for reference material belong on the [meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) site.

Comment: You could read the Declaration of Independence (first several pages) and the US Constitution. Federalist Papers is collection of newspaper articles by three of the founders.

Comment: @Xanne, thanks for advice!

Comment: If you read a classic in a subject you like, that will keep you engaged, and you will read the whole book. English of 100 years ago was more flowery, so you will build vocabulary by learning in context (not memorize and forget flash cards).

Comment: @Yosef Baskin, Thank you, sir. other forums have adves to try 'federalis papers', hope that will be useful just like you said)